# i get the Data just in subscribe bracket

Tags: angular, typescript

This is My Code:
getTransaction(transactionRef: string){

```
    this.partnerportalService
        .getTransaction(transactionRef)
        .subscribe(data=>{
            this.transactionData = data;
            console.log("Return the Data ", this.transactionData);
        });
    console.log("Return Undefined", this.transactionData);

}
```

Comment: yes because http observables are asynchronous.

Comment: It is an async function. You need to place the content inside the subscription.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe` is **asynchronous**, meaning that it is going to be executed sometime later, however the line that contains `console.log("Return Undefined", this.transactionData);` is outside of the `subscribe` function scope and is instead executed **synchronously**. This means that `console.log("Return Undefined", this.transactionData);` will execute **before** `this.transactionData = data;`, hence it prints `undefined`.